# Combining three row/table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I must connect three table. My code works great with two tables but doesn't work with three table. I use PostgreSQL 9.4.9 in Debian.

Code with 2 tables (WORKS):

```
SELECT 
manufactures.manufacturename
,products.productname
FROM products
INNER JOIN manufactures
ON manufactures.manufactureid=products.productmanufacturer;
```

Code with 3 tables (Doesn't works)

```
SELECT 
manufactures.manufacturename
,products.productname
,languages.languagename
FROM products
INNER JOIN manufactures
ON manufactures.manufactureid=products.productmanufacturer
INNER JOIN languages
ON languages.languagename=products.productlanguage;
```

Error message

```
baza_testowa=# SELECT 
baza_testowa-# manufactures.manufacturename
baza_testowa-# ,products.productname
baza_testowa-# ,languages.languagename
baza_testowa-# FROM products
baza_testowa-# INNER JOIN manufactures
baza_testowa-# ON manufactures.manufactureid=products.productmanufacturer
baza_testowa-# INNER JOIN languages
baza_testowa-# ON languages.languagename=products.productlanguage;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 9: ON languages.languagename=products.productlanguage;
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
     Table "public.products"
       Column        |  Type   |                          Modifiers                           
---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 productid           | integer | not null default nextval('products_productid_seq'::regclass)
 productmanufacturer | integer | not null
 productname         | text    | not null
 productlanguage     | integer | 
Indexes:
    "products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (productid)
```

```
                                 Table "public.manufactures"
     Column      |  Type   |                              Modifiers                               
-----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 manufactureid   | integer | not null default nextval('manufactures_manufactureid_seq'::regclass)
 manufacturename | text    | not null
Indexes:
"manufactures_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (manufactureid)
```

```
      Table "public.languages"
    Column    |  Type   |                           Modifiers                            
--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 languageid   | integer | not null default nextval('languages_languageid_seq'::regclass)
 languagename | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "languages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (languageid)
```

Comment: The error message says that `products.productlanguage` is an integer. Is it really what you want that it is the same as `languages.languagename`?

Answer (score 1):

languages.languagename is text but products.productlanguage is integer, you can't compare them

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make **JOIN**s on columns that are different types. You can use **explicit type casting**, if you really want `products.productlanguage` to be an integer and `languages.languagename` to be text. So in your case it should look like this:

```
SELECT manufactures.manufacturename, products.productname, languages.languagename
FROM products
INNER JOIN manufactures ON manufactures.manufactureid = products.productmanufacturer
INNER JOIN languages ON languages.languagename = products.productlanguage::text;
```